# SaltStack eauth error with pam retval = 7 (PAM_PERM_DENIED)

Tags: salt-stack

My salt-master is running as a non-root user "salt". When eauth is turned on, PAM return value is 7. It seems pam.auth access is denied by PAM to "salt" user.

https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/26091

Would anyone be kind enough to show me what I need to configure in PAM?

Comment: "salt" user needs READ acl to /etc/shadow. 

  >   setfacl u:salt:r /etc/shadow

https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/7762

Comment: Is that the solution to your issue? If so, please post it as an answer (and accept it afterwards) - it's going to be valuable for future!

Comment: Hi @AdamMichalik, please refer to the github issue link mentioned above.

This command fixes these issues:

setfacl -m u:salt:r /etc/shadow

For "salt" substitute the salt master process run user.

The problem is that pam auth won't work for non-root users trying to authenticate another user. In this case our non-root user is the user under which the salt master runs. Non-root users can't read "/etc/shadow", which would be required for pam authentication of other users.

Solution: Add an access control rule enabling the salt master run user to read "/etc/shadow".

Answer (score 0):

External authentication using PAM needs salt-master process to be run as `root`. You don't need anything to be configured (of course except external_authentication part in master configuration file). Installing PAM, making sure `login` script is present and running salt-master as `root` is enough.

Check [here](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/develop/topics/eauth/index.html) for further information.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to get away - running salt-master as root.